# Docker container on raspberry with linux/arm64

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile

I have the next docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Pitman.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./Pitman.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "Pitman.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Pitman.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Pitman.dll"]
```

and I'm running the build command:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 -t latest .
```

tagging and pushing the image to docker hub

```
docker tag 8986ff79cb02 myid/pitman:latest
docker push myid/pitman
```

downloading the image on raspberry pi:

```
sudo docker pull myid/pitman:latest
```

and when I run the image

```
sudo docker run  8986ff79cb02
```

I get the next error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

after building the image on my rpi I get this

```
Step 6/15 : RUN dotnet restore "./Pitman.csproj"
 ---> Running in 8562957be5d6
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "./Pitman.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Did you build the image on the same architecture as you're running the image? I think that might be the problem.

Comment: I'm building the image on windows, I'm now trying to build the image on rpi

Comment: Try also changing your base images to the ARM ones. I think the ones you have selected don't work on ARM: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-runtime/ (the "Linux arm64 Tags" section). "Latest" is mult-arch, but your selected "3.1-buster-slim" is amd64 only.

Comment: @gunr2171 your suggestion fixed the problem I had :), you can make please an answer to approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the base image you're using for the final docker image:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim
```

That image only supports amd64 (not ARM). You need to choose another base image that either supports ARM-only or multi-arch (amd64 + arm64). [For example](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-runtime/), "latest" and "3.1.8" at time of writing are multi-arch.

I know for a fact that if you build an image on ARM (with an ARM base image) it will be able to run on any ARM system. I've never done multi-arch builds before, so I don't know if choosing a multi-arch base image, building on amd64, then trying to run on arm64, will work (but based on your comment it sounds like it did).